# Why mysql.connecter python prepared statement returns string in bytearray

Tags: python, prepared-statement, mariadb

**Environment: Python 3.5.2, MySQL.Connector 2.0.4, on MariaDB Server 10.1.14**

Why the prepared cursor returns string values in bytearray, while the standard cursor returns normal string?

For the same call with the same instance, my **Prepared** Cursor Outputs:

```
[(11, bytearray(b'1234567890'), None),
 (17, bytearray(b'1234567799'), bytearray(b'abc@outlook.com'))]
```

While the **standard** version give the desired output:

```
[(11, '1234567890', None),
 (17, '1234567799', 'abc@outlook.com')]
```

**Standard Version Code:**

```
def query_userdb(query, arg):
    retVal = None
    cnx = mariadb.connect(**DB_CONFIG_USERS)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, arg)
    if cursor.rowcount != 0:
        retVal = cursor.fetchall()
    cnx.commit()
    cnx.close()
    return retVal
```

And for the **prepared** version I've only changed the cursor declaration into

```
    cursor = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
```

**How can I make the prepared cursor returns string correctly?**

Comment: Are you using mysql or mariadb?

Comment: ops, forget to say that, i'm using MariaDB 10.1

Comment: Actually, I've found some related documentations which gives the insight of the problem cause https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-2-0-0.html , but still now able solve it..

Answer (score 0):

To get a string you can use:

```
my_bytearray.decode("utf-8")
```

In your case using a list comprehension:

```
retVal = [(id,col2.decode("utf-8"),col3.decode("utf-8") for id,col2,col3 in retVal]
```

Or better to handle `None` values in the third column:

```
retVal = [(id,col2.decode("utf-8"),(col3 if col3 is None else col3.decode("utf-8")) for id,col2,col3 in retVal]
```